# Atollic stm32 how to prevent from flashing some parts of the flash?

Tags: stm32, linker-scripts, flash-memory

I'm using last pages of flash to store some parameters like this:

```
__attribute__((__section__(".storageFlash"))) Parameters flashParameters;
```

Flash is splitted in two parts:

```
FLASH (rx)              : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 510K
FLASH_STORAGE (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x0807F800, LENGTH = 2K
```

...

```
.storageFlash :
{
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(storageFlash)
    . = ALIGN(4);
} >FLASH_STORAGE
```

To make debug easier, I would like to preserve those pages from being overriden each time I debug ( = flash )  a new binary.

What's the way to? I'm using Atollic as an STM32 environment.

Comment: I usually (it s not the best way probably) split the memory into different memory regions. It is not universal but usually I place this king of segments at the end of flash so it is not a problem at all.

Comment: That's what I did (added in the question) but all the regions are written when flashing the code.

Comment: I do this same way.. add `(NOLOAD)`,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add to section definition: `(NOLOAD)`

```
.storageFlash (NOLOAD) :
{
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(storageFlash)
    . = ALIGN(4);
} >FLASH_STORAGE
```